# Suggestions for the Community get-to-know questionnaire

Tags: discussion, community

You may be aware of [this thread](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3747/community-get-to-know-qa).

Obviously, the questions are tailored to ask of (future) moderators to express their views. This may not be completely identical with the needs of "getting to know" each other in a more profound sense.

Therefore, the purpose of this thread is to enable you to suggest additional questions (or striking thereof), i.e. to actively shape the questionnaire from what it is to what you think it should be like.

Answer (score 2):

You might ask things such as the following:

- Where did you receive a formal education?
- What topics did you study?
- What books are you currently reading?
- What publications do you have to your credit?
- Are you on social media besides stack exchange?

Some people may not want the above information known especially if they are using a pseudonym here.